# Should I use debug build executable or release build executable to install a windows service?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I do not know which exe to use when install a windows service? in bin or obj?

Because the choice here is later related to service debugging. I find out that there is some differences bewteen debugging a debug build exe and release build exe. It seems to me that debugging a debug build exe is simpler. But my instint tells me that I should install a release build exe service.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that usual for people to automatically downvote every little question that seems a bit "out of the bounds" ? Without any answer/comment or anything else besides ?

People register on a forum **designed to** help people and share experiences and they just make them feel like their question is too absurd or stupid to be answered by someone of  their level.

You are a wall to curiosity and improvement and i sincerely hope, from the bottom of my heart, that you'll all die in a festival of atrocities ! best regards =)
<\aside>

**That being said, here is my answer :**

The best thing you can do is to follow this guide : [Attach a Debugger to a Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-debug-windows-service-applications)

**HOWEVER**, if you are in a configuration that doesn't allow you to do this or if you prefer going into logs, follow your instinct : Use release one.

**First, some errors won't appear in Debug but they could in release.**

**Second**, and the most important one, the release will be potentially **distributed to customers**.